# Strange SD card behaviour

Tags: linux, sd-card

I have a Sandisk 8GB SDHC card. Yesterday I was trying to write a Raspberry Pi OS image to it. But it fails in the middle. From then on, the card seems to be "dead" in my desktop PC since it no longer writeable.

This morning I tried to put it into my Sony Nex camera and format. No luck, it says "SD card error".

Finally I tried my Panasonic camcorder. Surprisingly, it formats the card happily. I tried to record short videos and there is NO error!

Now the card was back alive! my Desktop PC sd card can read it again. But I don't know what happened, and I tried writing of OS image again. The same error occurs (and it was keep dead until I re-format it with the camcorder).

I want to ask who knows more about SD card, what actually causes this problem? Is this SD card still reliable? I have confirmed, once the SD card back to alive, my camera can fill it with shots without difficulty.

I need to mention that the command I used to write the image is

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=osimge of=/dev/sdf oflag=direct
```

The reason I use `oflag=direct` is that I want to avoid using `sync` after the writing and bypass the OS caching.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have just confirmed when the SD card is in "dead" status it fails on ANY attempt to access, even running another `dd` will fail immediately. Plug and unplug does not help as well.

Comment: did you format the card first? I haven't done much with the `dd` command; but when I burn my RPi cards on Windows I have to format the disk using a seperate program before I actually burn the .img to the card..

Comment: Any formatting would be overwritten by the `dd` anyway.

Comment: @evamvid: If that is really so, that's some sort of Windows specific limitation. There's no point in creating a file system on a device you're going to rewrite anyway. And creating a file system is basically what *formatting* means in the DOS/Windows world.

Comment: @PavelSimerda you're right; I guess that is a Windows-specific (maybe to wipe it before writing to it)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine that you'd have a somewhat corrupted partition table as the RPi write failed half way. I would have immediately retried to rewrite the same OS image. Sometimes the drivers for in built SD card readers can be poor/buggy; the other day I got my first real kernel panic in years by unloading and reloading the module for my sd card reader. Coincedentally I was also writing a raspi image! After a reboot the card was writable again; the image wrote to the card fine the second time. 
If it happens again, look at

```
dmesg
```

and

```
fdisk -l
```

and look for references to (in this case) sdf. Also look at

```
ls -al /dev/sdf*
```

if there is just sdf (i.e. no sdf1 sdf2 etc), then no valid partition table is seen, and either fdisk, parted or other similar tool needs to be run to write a new one, followd by a mkfs of some sort. e.g.

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdf1
```